# How to use $resource to configure $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider during config (or run?) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I want to set up an Angular UI Router $urlRouterProvider $stateProvider "dynamically", based on some configuration read from a JSON resource. I've tried:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $resource) {
```

but that doesn't work ("Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $resource from mui.jsAngularAddressbookApp") because (I do understand) "you can only inject Providers (not instances) into the config blocks". So then I tried:

```
.run(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $resource) {
```

but that cannot work either ("Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $stateProviderProvider <- $stateProvider") because (again I do understand the principle) "You can only inject instances (not Providers) into the run blocks".

I've hacked / worked around it by just using jQuery.getJSON instead of $resource, but that's "not the AngularJS way" of course (does it have any real disadvantages though?).

What's the "proper" solution to this?

Comment: Actually this is probably a current limitation of Angular UI Router... note https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/874 :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer yet, but have managed to access the ui-router at config time. Credits go mostly to another github issue reporter https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/120 My gist on how to access the config at runtime is in the thread as well.

At this time you can only add routes and it will throw an error if you try to add a route more than once. Sorry for the CoffeeScript. For the moment I am still looking at a way to load the routes asynchronously.

```
angular.module('app').provider 'RouteConfig',
  ['$stateProvider', ($stateProvider) ->
    # this will configure the routes from the received json
    # using $stateProvider.state() like in app.config
    configurator = ($http) ->
      console.log $stateProvider
    updateRoutes: ->
      configService.get().then (conf) ->
        # add routes here from 'conf'

    @$get = ['configService', (configService, $http) ->
      new configurator(configService, $http)
   ]
  return
 ]
```

Comment: I just ran into this project: https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-detour which seems to allow runtime routing config:
"allows runtime editing of configuration" and "supports lazy-loading/updating definitions from a server through AJAX"